# Is There a way to check if(do.condion=='11') in Groovy DSL

Tags: groovy, dsl

Is There a way to check `if(do.condion=='11')` in Groovy DSL.

```
if(object.member == '2') //then do my logic
```

I am not able to use `==`. its not throwing any error it just going to next statement

Comment: Probably it is... Any context?

Comment: Since it's going to the next statement the expression is evaluating as false. What did your dsl look like?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa
`AcceptILPN {
   input scanCase
   if(workflowParameters.reserveVerificationModeParm.equals("1")) next AcceptSKUQuantity
   if(workflowParameters.validateCarton.equals("1")) next AcceptOLPNOrTote
   if(workflowDO.nextDtlPresent) next AcceptILPN
   else next AcceptPickCart
  }`
It is going to the else even my first if statement is true.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your DSL correctly, formatted for clarity it looks like this:

```
AcceptILPN { 
    input scanCase        

    if(workflowParameters.reserveVerificationModeParm.equals("1")) next AcceptSKUQuantity 
    if(workflowParameters.validateCarton.equals("1")) next AcceptOLPNOrTote 
    if(workflowDO.nextDtlPresent) next AcceptILPN else next AcceptPickCart 
}
```

To see what's happening, here's the same code with a more formal syntax:

```
AcceptILPN { 
    input(scanCase)     

    if(workflowParameters.reserveVerificationModeParm.equals("1")) {
        next(AcceptSKUQuantity)
    }

    if(workflowParameters.validateCarton.equals("1")) {
        next(AcceptOLPNOrTote)
    )

    if(workflowDO.nextDtlPresent) {
        next(AcceptILPN)
    } else {
        next(AcceptPickCart)
    }
}
```

As you can see, even when the first `if` expression evaluates to true the following `if` blocks will execute because there's nothing (at least visible in the DSL) that exits the `Closure` prematurely. It seems you're looking for something like this:

```
AcceptILPN { 
    input(scanCase)     

    if(workflowParameters.reserveVerificationModeParm.equals("1")) {
        next(AcceptSKUQuantity)
    }

    else if(workflowParameters.validateCarton.equals("1")) {
        next(AcceptOLPNOrTote)
    )

    else if(workflowDO.nextDtlPresent) {
        next(AcceptILPN)
    } else {
        next(AcceptPickCart)
    }
}
```